# Update a canvas children from a saved txt file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas, updates

I am trying to update a canvas from xaml code that i have in a txt file.
What i have done is a save function that saves the canvas that surrounds everything.

Then i am trying to create a load function that opens that txt file and updates the canvas with the data from that file.

But my problem is that it do not update the existing canvas but instedd ad a new one so i have 2.

my question is how do i fix my load function so it do not add a new canvas but only adds the saved canvas children.

Right now my load function locks like this:

```
        if (userClickedOK == true)
        {
            StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(dlg.FileName);
            string text = sR.ReadToEnd();
            sR.Close();

            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(text);
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);

            Canvas canvas1 = (Canvas)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

            parentWindow.canvas.Children.Clear(); // clear the existing children
            parentWindow.grid.Children.Add(canvas1);
```

Eddit: new code:

```
        if (userClickedOK == true)
        {
            StreamReader sR = new StreamReader(dlg.FileName);
            string text = sR.ReadToEnd();
            sR.Close();

            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(text);
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);

            parentWindow.canvas = (Canvas)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

            parentWindow.grid.Children.Add(parentWindow.canvas);
         }
```

// Nivres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe i did solve it.

```
            parentWindow.grid.Children.Remove(parentWindow.canvas);
            parentWindow.canvas = (Canvas)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
            parentWindow.grid.Children.Add(parentWindow.canvas);
```

With this i only get one Canvas, but maybe it is the wrong way to go.